# How to use the sphero_ros Python API?

Tags: python, ros, sphero

I have installed [sphero_ros](http://mmwise.github.io/sphero_ros/tutorials.html) on my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I've made it as far as being able to issue single rostopic commands to the Sphero via the Terminal. However, I would like to use the [Python API](http://mmwise.github.io/sphero_ros/api.html#id1) instead, only I can't find any documentation on where I would even start to accomplish this. In essence, I'm looking for a step-by-step guide or a "Hello World" script of some sort. Can anyone help me?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [davinellulinvega](https://github.com/davinellulinvega)'s instructions on the project's GitHub [Issues](https://github.com/mmwise/sphero_ros/issues/6) page. Here is my adapted version of the test.py file that comes with the driver:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from sphero_driver import sphero_driver
import time

sphero = sphero_driver.Sphero()

while True:
    try:
        sphero.connect()
        break
    except:
        print '\nTrying to connect again!'
        pass

time.sleep(2)

sphero.set_rgb_led(255, 0, 0, 0, False)
time.sleep(1)
sphero.set_rgb_led(0, 255, 0, 0, False)
time.sleep(1)
sphero.set_rgb_led(0, 0, 255, 0, False)
time.sleep(1)
```

If you want to connect to a specific Sphero, use

```
sphero = sphero_driver.Sphero('Sphero','01:23:45:67:89:AB')
```

instead, where the second argument is your Sphero's address.